# How can I tie MVC to a deployed Web Forms on IIS while preserving session state?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We currently have a Web Forms application deployed on IIS. Our goal right now is to start a new MVC application that we can route to from the Web Forms application while being able to retain session state across these two different applications that reside together on IIS.

Essentially, we want a Web Forms application and an MVC application to be treated as a single application on IIS, preserving session state when we navigate between the two applications.

The main reason we're trying to achieve this is that we want to simplify things (I am a new intern developer without Web Forms experience), and my supervisor doesn't want to have to deal with ViewState and Web Forms technology now that we've had a good transition to MVC with other applications we've worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other than in-process session state storage. For example you can use SQL database, or AppFabric Cache (aka Velocity). It is very easy, only web.config change. You can configure any number of different applications to share the session this way.

HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Configuring an ASP.NET Session State Provider (Windows Server AppFabric Caching)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can [mix classic WebForms with ASP.NET MVC](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Allan/Dates/112230/2/EPiServer-Pie-with-freshly-cut-MVC/) in a single ASP.NET application. And because it is a single ASP.NET application now, you can share session state.

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to have the two applications exist as separate solutions and still share state across them? Or is mixing them into a single application our best bet?

Comment: @SCS, different projects means different ASP.NET applications => no session sharing.